# Adding a date column and a nvarchar column together

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have 3 columns in my Test table that look like this

```
DATE        TIME       Combined
2015-08-17  16:07:49
2015-08-18  08:13:23
2015-08-18  08:13:24
2015-08-18  08:14:36
```

What I want to do is combine the Date and Time column to populate the Combined Column

The DATE column is actually a date Data Type.

The Time column is actually a nvarchar(MAX) Data Type.

I'm not exactly sure what to use for the Combined column.

Is it possible to add the two together as they are or do I have to convert the time and if so how do I do this conversion?

I have used:

```
alter table [dbo].[Test] alter column [TIME] time(0)
```

and have received this error message:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Does anyone have have any insight for me on this and if I even need to convert it?

Comment: You probably have an invalid value somewhere

Comment: If its the TIME column won't it set the default to 00:00:00?

Comment: No. It needs to have a valid, convertible value.

Answer (score 2):

The data type for the `combined` column should be `datetime2` (or `datetime`) as that is what it will hold.

You can't add a varchar value to a date type value, but to populate it you can cast the `[date]` column to a `datetime` and add the varchar string with the time part to it like this:

```
update dbo.test set combined = cast([date] as datetime) + [time] from dbo.test
```

This does however rely on the values in the `[time]` column being valid, and the error message you get indicates that some value(s) isn't, so you need to identify and correct those values first.

[Example SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb9fa/1)

Answer (score 0):

for Display try,
select [Date]+' ' + Time as  CombinedColumn from Test